# Can $f(x)>g(x)$ be implied from $\frac{df(x)}{dx}\gt \frac{dg(x)}{dx}$?

Tags: functions, derivatives

I am new to functions. My question is Can $f(x)>g(x)$ be implied from $\frac{df(x)}{dx}\gt \frac{dg(x)}{dx}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that $f(a)>g(a)$ at $a$ and $f'(x)\geq g'(x)$  for all $x>a$, you can deduce $f(x)>g(x)$ for all $x>a$ inductively.  But the derivative in and of itself has nothing to do with the value of the function at the point at which you are taking the derivative.

Comment: I'll add that if one switches the roles of strict inequalities, the result holds.

Comment: Really thanks, but please elaborate your second line(But the derivative...) for arithmetic functions > Z+.

Answer (score 2):

No. $f'(x) > g'(x)$ only says that $f(x)-g(x)$ is increasing, it can still be negative. Take for example (with $x>0\;$):  $$f(x) = \frac{1}{x+1},\quad g(x) = \frac{1}{x} $$
Then 
$$f(x)-g(x) = -\frac{1}{x(x+1)} < 0 \quad\text{and}\quad
f'(x)-g'(x) = \frac{2x+1}{x^2(x+1)^2} > 0$$

Answer (score 2):

A counter example:

Consider f(x)=$\sin x$ and g(x)=$\cos x$. When x $\in$ [0,$\frac{\pi}{4}$] g(x)>f(x).

g'(x)=-sin x and f'(x)=cos x. Hence f'(x)$\gt$g'(x) when x$\in [0,\frac{\pi}{4}] $

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x)=-\frac 1x$ and $g(x)=0$ on the positive real axis. Then $f'(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}>0=g'(x)$ yet $f(x)<g(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a horizontal line $g$ and an increasing line $f$.  Then $f'>g'=0$, but certainly we need not have $f>g$ everywhere.